# How do I get the time (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) of my KissMetrics events?

Tags: analytics

Do I need to make my own tool to get that from s3 json dumps of the raw event data, or can I magick the Reports view to show it somehow instead of just filtering on it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears KissMetrics themselves offer no better tip than doing it on your own from the `_t` unixtime integers in the daily json dumps to Amazon s3 they offer.

(Though their response was more voluminous and more salesy about other features you might want to use if you were having a different problem they have implemented a user interface for. I will spare you the details.)